# How do I find the pinout of this touchpad?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, touch-panel, elan

I have this dead `Acer Aspire One 756-877B2ss` laptop computer from 2012 that I have completely torn down, and I would like to repurpose its trackpad for Arduino or Raspberry Pi

What's especially confusing to me is how many soldering points there are given that ps2 or USB, whichever is used, only needs 4 wires including power, but here there are many more soldering points and 8 wires in the ribbon cable plug

I searched all over online, but couldn't seem to find anything regarding its pinout.

What's written on it:

```
Elan 201211-042201 Rev.A
CK 77-1 3 94V-0
E85792
```

What's written on the chip:

```
Elan
33200V-3600
1217 BD12403
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: Touchpad back]

Comment: Have you looked at the chip's data sheet?

Comment: @Andyaka I searched for it, but couldn't find it

Comment: what soldering points are you talking about? ... the TouchPad uses a connector

Comment: @jsotola see the brown dots labeled with T<number> ? Those are soldering points. Both connectors and a soldering points are possible here.

Comment: those are test points ... you could solder wires to them

Comment: @jsotola That doesn't tell me what they do though :-/